# Why my code inside useEffect is not runnig and not fetching the url? what am i missing?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to show the value fetched from this api where i am getting category from another component. I am attatching my code here.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Categories from './Categories'

function Joke({ category }) {
    console.log("category selected for joke = " + category);
    const jokeId = category;
    const [joke, setJoke] = useState('');
    const [jokeURL, setJokeURL] = useState('');

    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log('......... = '+category);
        fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category={category}')
            .then(res => res.json)
            .then(res => setJoke(res));
    }, []);
    console.log("Joke for "+jokeId+" = "+joke);
    return (
        <div>
            {jokeId == ''
                ? <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' , marginTop:'100px' }}>Please choose a category to begin<p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}></p></p>
                : <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' , marginTop:'100px'}}>Selected Category: {jokeId}</p>
            }

        </div>
    )
}

export default Joke
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Template Literals in fetch function and one more thing is don't forget to write parenthesis. It is not `json` it is `json()`.

```
useEffect(() =>{
  console.log('......... = '+category);
  fetch(`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=${category}`)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => setJoke(res));
}, []);
```

This one should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
useEffect(() =>{
  fetch(`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=${category}`) // look here
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => setJoke(res));
}, []);
```

DEMO : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hfkcwo?file=src%2FJoke.js)

Comment: This gave an error```Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): 'json' called on an object that does not implement interface Response.

   9 | 
  10 |    useEffect(() => {
  11 |        console.log('......... = ' + category);
> 12 |        fetch(`https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=${category}`) 
     | ^  13 |            .then(res => res.json)
  14 |            .then(res => setJoke(res));
  15 |    }, []);```

Comment: @Yogesh check the demo